# How to end scheduled task A with scheduled task B when ANY users disconnects?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-7, automation, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to execute scheduled task B that should stop scheduled task A through a bat file containing the following command:

```
schtasks /End /TN "scheduled task A"
```

Scheduled task B should run when ANY user disconnects form his account.

I've tried without success different options under the General tab, adding                   "SYSTEM" user, “Run with highest privileges”.

The problem is that scheduled task A never ends through the automatic execution of scheduled task B, but only when I manually execute scheduled task B from the Schedule Task MMC.

If I look at Task Scheduler events in Event Viewer, I can see that task B is never automatically executed as it should when ANY user disconnects.

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Any chance you are confusing "disconnects" with, perhaps, "logs out" and/or "locks the computer"?

Comment: Your comment was useful to find a solution. To run a logout script this is working:
Begin the task: On an event
Log: System
Source: Winlogon
Event ID: 7002